# What is the value of C in this integral equation?

Tags: integral-equations

Consider the following integral equation:
$$\int_0^1 С(yW(x))W^3(x)\,dx=F(y),$$
$$
W(x)=0.5( \cosh(kx)-\cos(kx)-A( \sinh(kx)-\sin(kx)))
$$

$F$ is known.

$A= \frac{ \cosh(k)+\cos(k)}{ \sinh(k)+\sin(k)}$.

What is the value of $C$?

Comment: C is function  which need to find. k - is known constant